# ggplot scatter creating uniform points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a scatter plot with ggplot to show time watching TV on x axis and immigrant sentiment on y axis.

The code I am using is

```
ggplot(totalTV, 
       aes(x = dfnew.TV.watching..total.time.on.average.weekday, 
           y = dfnew.Immigrant.Sentiment)) + 
  geom_point()
```

I am getting this output

[image: The scatterplot]

My table is so, with first variable being character, and subsequent two being numeric:

[image: My table is so]

Any idea on how to produce a representative scatter of the outcome?

Cheers

Comment: The scatter plot looks correct for your data but it seems like a scatter plot might not be the best choice when you have two discrete variables like that. What are you trying to show exactly? Also, be sure to share example data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (not as an image) so we can easily run/test the code.

Comment: If there are overlapping points, you may wish to consider `geom_jitter` instead of `geom_point`, perhaps with `alpha = 0.5` (or any other number < 1), so that the data spread becomes clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples using the `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Original
ggplot(mtcars,aes(factor(cyl),mpg)) + 
  geom_point()

# Jitter
ggplot(mtcars,aes(factor(cyl),mpg)) + 
  geom_jitter(width = .2) # Control spread with width

# Violin plot
ggplot(mtcars,aes(factor(cyl),mpg)) + 
  geom_violin()

# Boxplot 
ggplot(mtcars,aes(factor(cyl),mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot()


# Remember that different geoms can be combined
ggplot(mtcars,aes(factor(cyl),mpg)) + 
  geom_violin() + 
  geom_jitter(width = .2)

# Or something more exotic ala Raincloud-plots
# https://micahallen.org/2018/03/15/introducing-raincloud-plots/
```

[image]